# Best practices for single activity app and view models

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I just started programming for android and, as soon as my application started growing, I began to ask myself questions about best practices.

I have a single activity application with a Room database.
I have the following views:

- list of products
- list of users and products they bought ( this is a join table of ids)
- products statistics
- other non relevant views

All the mentioned views basically require to access the "products" table in the database. One requires all the objects, another requires to get selected ids and the last requires to read specific columns.

What I did was to create a products view model that is scoped in the main activity (global scope since I have only one actitivy).
The first view that is opened will load the products from the database while all the following ones can simply access them from the common view model.

Is this approach acceptable? How does this scales with the database size and multiple tables?

I'm practically loading the full database in memory for the entire life of the application  and I don't really like it.
The alternative is to have separate view models for each view (as is suggested in basic examples), but, assuming the user going back and forth between 2 of the main views, I would keep fetching and releasing data from the database..

Any suggestion is highly appreciated as I would like to fix this before reaching some resources limit =)

Thank you

Comment: *I would keep fetching and releasing data from the database* normally that data is cached in a repository that is between the viewmodel and the database. Each view has its own viewmodel but all viewmodels can use the same repository/data

Comment: Thank you @Tim Castelijns. My app uses a singleton database and repository. Is the caching automatic for Room queries or is it something I have to implement?

Comment: you have to implement those by storing data in database. room is just a wrapper around sqlite.

Comment: Thank you! Could you reformat these as an answer, maybe providing a snippet about how to observe cached data from a view model, so that I can accept and close this?